# Jquery conditional (if) statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to lock the scroll when overlay is open. So I wrote this code using jquery, but it doesn't work.

CSS:

```
<style>
/* Lock Scroll */
html.no-scroll {overflow: hidden;}
</style>
```

my Jquery(js) script:

```
<script>
if(("#overlay").css("display") == "flex"){   
        $('html').addClass('no-scroll');   
    } else {  
        $('html').removeClass('no-scroll');   
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: Make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I created an example, notice that when clicking on the `<button>` the **overlay** is opened.

I used the same `.no-scroll` class with `overflow-hidden` to avoid scrolling.

I hope that the example can contribute to your project.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $html = $('html');

    $('#button-overlay').on('click', function() {
      $('#overlay').toggle('fast', function() {
        if( $html.hasClass('no-scroll') ) {
          $html.removeClass('no-scroll');
          return;
        }
        
        $html.addClass('no-scroll');
        // or
        //$('html').toggleClass('no-scroll');
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
   padding: 30px;
}

p { 
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .8;
  z-index: 998;
}

#button-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline;
  background: yellow;
  color: #333;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="button-overlay">Open Overlay</button>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Jeff! thanks for your help. For some reasons, I don't have to use toggleClass.. (it breaks the other part of the code) Do have any ideas on how to do this on the other way ?

Comment: You saved my life man!! This works perfectly. thanks a lot